# Secure Environment in android app statusbar

Tags: android, kotlin, security, statusbar

I get this question when I was looking in any banking,

payment-related apps show a specific icon that indicates a **secure environment**.

I search on google but I didn't find anything on there.

```
please check the below screenshot to better understand.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its a security feature called `Payment Protection` specially available in OPPO devices [`ColorOS 3.0 and above`] as of January, 2024.

You can just search it in the settings.

Payment Protection enhances the security of your financial information by **placing your payment apps in a secure location.**

While using the app or making transactions, a notification displaying **"Secured Environment"** will appear on the upper portion of the screen.

> Currently, there is no manual process for adding an app to the Payment
> Protection list, as ColorOS intelligently detects which apps require
> payment protection and enables it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I come across similar question as well, there is no much information about this, firstly I saw this in Samsung S-pay [website](https://samsung.com/levant/support/mobile-devices/s-pay-what-is-a-secure-environment-or-trusted-execution-environment/) saying:

> A Secure Environment is a physically segregated chip in the phone
> which only allows access to highly sensitive operations/information
> such as fingerprint and payment information. Normal applications and
> malware have no access to the information in a Secure Environment.

If you search more with the keyword `Trusted Execution Environment`, then you can realize it is a security standard specified in mobile environment. Like [this](https://www.trustonic.com/technical-articles/what-is-a-trusted-execution-environment-tee/).

So when your Android code are being executed in Trusted Execution Environment, then the "Secure Environment" sign will appear in the app bar to inform you that you are in secure transaction. As per my observation, it is mostly appear when we are using our fingerprint, that actually make sense as accessing fingerprint (or pin) require higher security standard.

Comment: updated link for s-pay - [here](https://www.samsung.com/my/samsung-pay/frequently-asked-questions/payment-security/)